# what is firebase equivalent of this Asynchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

this is my Asynchronous javascript practice

```
processArray();

        async function processArray() {
            for (const item of Myarray) {
                await delayedlog(item);
            }
        }

        function delayedlog(i) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(i);
            }, i * 5000);
        }
var Myarray = [1,2,3]
```

but when working with firebase we will not use set time out ,

**how to wait until the read operation completes & then continue to next function**

Comment: Nothing in what you shared seems related to Firebase. Where are you using this? It would also  be good to see the error that you get.

Comment: Actually i want to replace timeout with a firebase read operation , but it will not be executed in sequence one after one , so how to do it was question

Comment: Doesn't firebase return promises already (in contrast to `setTimeout`, which is why your example doesn't wait)? This would just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to make the `await delayedlog(item)` wait for the actual method, you will have to return a promise from `delayedlog`. You can do that with:

```
function delayedlog(i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i);
      resolve();
    }, i * 5000);
  });
}
```

The `await` in your calling code then waits until the `Promise` is resolved.